# Как определить и редактировать .data файл?

Tags: файлы

Мне нужно изменить содержимое сохранений которые хранятся в файле `.data`.

Как определить тип и редактировать эти файлы?

P.S.: при попытке открыть в txt появляются несвязанные символы и заголовок *Компания* data

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что это за формат файла? Добавьте подробности в сам вопрос, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1442339/edit). Если у вас linux, выполните команду `file имя_файла.data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правило расширения типа ***.data** ***.dat** используются каждой компанией, каждым разработчиком для файлов в которых находится важная для работы их ПО информация, и содержимое и формат таких данных нигде не стандартизирован, и полностью является творчеством программистов. Так же в подобных ситуациях иногда можно увидеть расширение типа ***.raw** или вообще файлы данных без расширения.

В отличии от тех же **.json* **.xml* такие файлы нигде не стандартизированы, авторами программ нигде не выкладывается описание как эти файлы читать или интерпретировать, и соответственно нет ни каких сведений о их содержимом и структуре.

В данной ситуации вам поможет только реверсинженеринг, то есть запуск вашей программы в дебаггере, и наблюдение за тем что записывается/читается из этого файла. Но обычно чтение внутренних файлов ПО это не правильное решение поставленной задачи

Но иногда при открытии в текстовом редакторе таких файлов можно узнать в их структуре что-то известное: на пример сжатый xml или json, часто внутри оказывается база данных sqlite3 или Firebird. В таких случаях можно попробовать "поугадывать" формат и даже что-то извлечь из него в случае успеха. Так же можно попробовать этот файл передать в утилиту file операционной системы linux, и эта утилита попробует угадать содержимое файла, если оно угадываемо